# confusion regarding treatment of $dx$ in a physics problem

Tags: derivatives, physics, convention

[image]

Consider a fixed, positive Point charge $q1$, kept at the origin. Another (positive) charge, $q2$, is being brought from $\infty$ to the point $(r,0)$, by an external agent *slowly*. We wish to calculate the work done by the external agent (and thus derive the "potential" of the point charge $q1$, being defined as $w_{ext}/q2$ (or as $-w_{electric}/q2$)). Suppose we consider a position $(x,0)$:

- The magnitude of force is going to be $kq1q2/x^2$. We will thus have, $\vec{F}=\dfrac{-kq1q2}{x^2}\hat{i}$.
- When we displace it from a position $(x,0)$ to $(x-dx,0)$, the displacement vector$(\vec{ds})$ will be $(x-dx)\hat{i}-x\hat(i)=-dx\hat{i}$.
- Using $dw$=$\vec{F}.\vec{ds}$, we will get $dw=\dfrac{kq1q2}{x^2}dx$. Upon integrating from $\infty$ (initial position) to $r$ (final position), we get :
  $$w_{ext}=-\dfrac{kq1q2}{r}$$ and thus
  $$V(r)= w_{ext}/q2 =-\dfrac{kq1}{r}$$
  which is completely absurd. I tried to be as rigorous as possible with the definitions, vectors etc and yet a -ve sign has crept in somewhere.

The only issue seems to be with the treatment of $dx$. Although , I took $dx$ to be the *magnitude* of displacement, and accounted for the direction by using $-\hat{i}$.A possible argument seems to be "$x$ decreases, so $dx$ is a negative quantity. So the "magnitude" should be $-dx$. My two concerns:

- What is then, the issue with displacement=$\vec{r_{final}} - \vec{r_{initial}}$ that simply yields $-dx\hat{i}$?
- Simply "putting" a - sign before $dx$ after claiming "$dx$ is negative" seems to be arbitrary. There should be an argument (like I presented in the previous bullet point) that will produce the - sign for the magnitude, and thus making the vector $(-dx)(-\hat{i})$.

The main essence of this problem seems to be *rigorously* defining what $dx$ actually represents, for a quantity $x$.

I believe the entire thing can be summarized by one question:

**What is wrong in writing displacement=$\vec{r_{final}} - \vec{r_{initial}}$ that simply yields $-dx\hat{i}$? If I had $(x+dx)$ instead of $(x-dx)$,then the derivation would be correct. But why is this the Case?**

Comment: The issue is that by putting the displacement vector $\vec{ds}$ as $-dx$ you've introduced an extra minus sign. For example, if I tell you $\xi$ is a non-zero number, does that mean $\xi>0$? Of course not. Similarly, just because I write $-\xi$ it doesn't make it a negative number. Take a look [at this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/520068/203278). The take-away message is that you should just let the limits of integration keep track of the sign.

Comment: Why is your $\vec{F}$ negative?  The force you are doing work against points to the right (both particles have positive charge), so $\vec{F}$ is parallel to $\hat{i}$.  (Note that if both are negative, the same results.  If the charges are opposite in sign, then $\vec{F}$ acquire the correct negative sign -- the particle does work falling in towards the particle at the origin.)

Comment: You are right, but $F$ is negative, because the work of the external agent shall be calculated. Therefore you can think of it as $F:=F_{ext}=-F_{particles}$.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the interval $[r,\infty)\subseteq\mathbb{R}$, the external force
$$F_{ext}:[r,\infty)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^3,\quad F_{ext}(x)=-\frac{kq1q2}{x^2}\hat{i}$$

and the given curve

$$s:[r,\infty)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^3,\quad s(x)=x\hat{i}$$
along the work shall be calculated.

You can calculate the external work by choosing the right integration direction, i.e. integration from $\infty$ to $r$:

$$
\begin{align}
W_{ext}=\int_\infty^r F_{ext}\cdot ds
\end{align}$$

Alternatively you can calculate the external work by letting the so called displacement vector $ds$ point into the other direction and "just take the sum of that", i.e. integrate from $r$ to $\infty$ along $(-ds)$:

$$
\begin{align}
W_{ext}=\int_r^\infty F_{ext}\cdot (-ds)
\end{align}
$$

Actually, it is the same, since

$$\int_\infty^r F_{ext}\cdot ds=-\int_r^\infty  F_{ext}\cdot ds=\int_r^\infty F_{ext}\cdot (-ds)$$

If you do both, you will integrate from $r$ to $\infty$ again instead of $\infty$ to $r$. You will have reversed the integration direction and the direction of the displacement vector.

Note that you cannot change the given curve $s$, because this would be an integration along *a different* curve.  However you can change the direction of integration by changing the direction of the displacement vector $ds$. For that, see the later discussion.

Finally it holds

$$
\begin{align}
W_{ext}=-\int^\infty_r F_{ext}\cdot ds
&=-\int_r^\infty\cos(\pi)\frac{kq1q2}{x^2}dx\\
&=kq1q2\int_r^\infty\frac{1}{x^2}dx\\
&=kq_1q_2\Big(-x^{-1}\Big|_{x=r}^{x=\infty}\Big)\\
&=kq_1q_2\frac{1}{r}
\end{align}$$

**Concerning the problem with the negative displacement vector:**

This is the case, because you are thinking about a different curve then. A curve that is starting at $\infty\hat{i}$ and ending in $r\hat{i}$. Then its parametrisation is a little inconvenient to write down, but it is possible to change the direction of the curve: Let $R>r>0$. Define

$$s:[r,R]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^3,\quad s(x)= (R+r-x)\hat{i}$$

Now this curve starts in $R\hat{i}$ and ends in $r\hat{i}$, i.e. "walks" in the right direction, such that

$$ds=-dx\hat{i}$$

Then, since the curve has already the right starting and endpoints, you will calculate the work *along this(!) curve*:

$$W_{ext}=\lim_{R\rightarrow \infty}\int_r^R F_{ext}(x)\cdot ds=\lim_{R\rightarrow \infty} \int_r^R \cos(0)\frac{kq1q2}{x^2}dx=\int_{r}^\infty\frac{kq1q2}{x^2}dx=kq_1q_2\frac{1}{r}$$

So it is not only important to know the curve itself (the set in $\mathbb{R}^3$, that is the curve), but also its orientation (the direction it is "walking" / its start and endpoints) if you want to integrate something *along a curve*. ($ds$ will always point from start to endpoint.)

But it's just easier to think of a fixed curve and just swap start and endpoints of the integral, if you want to integrate into the other direction.

Comment: I think you have missed the point (or I am misreading your answer), But the expected result was supposed to be $+Kq1q2/r$

Comment: Thank you. I misunderstood your question. I've done an edit to my answer and hope this will clarify your problem.

Comment: Nice answer, +1, but my major query is still unresolved. I have edited the question and added whats *really bothering me* at the end.

Comment: I've posted another edit, to clarify  *integration along a curve*.